# Turn off an annoying Inspection, in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm working with Android Lollypop's `JobScheduler`.  Android Studio is flagging this code:

```
JobScheduler js = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
```

... as an error.  It compiles fine.  Studio, though, thinks it knows all of the legal services, and marks it.

I'm guessing that this is an "Inspection".  I searched inspections for the error message, which begins "Must be one of: Context.POWER_SERVICE" and didn't find anything.

This leads me to the specific question: "how can I turn off this, particular, annoying error".  Also, the more general question: "In general, if an inspection is annoying me, how do I find it, so that I can turn it off?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

General way to disable inspections you don't want in IntelliJ based IDEs:

1. Navigate to the part of the code which shows warning caused by the inspection
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. From that menu you can navigate to *Edit inspection profile setting*
4. There you can either change the level of inspection (error/warning/info/...) or disable it entirely

Alternatively you can find list of all inspections in *Settings/Inspections*.