# No way to access Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE

Tags: android, service, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to access the `Usage_Stats_Service` in lollipop through this :

```html
final UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager=(UsageStatsManager)this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
```

I can go to the `Context` class and see how this constant exist but Android Studio keeps saying that it is not a valid constant.

I have tried to use the literal string too but it seems `getSystemService` has a constraint to only accept `@ServiceName` constants.

I have spent almost 2 hours into this without finding out what is hapenning. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698366/cant-use-lollipop-specific-classes-in-android-studio

Comment: I saw this and tried it before asking. I cleaned caches, etc... and the issue is still there. I think it is not a good way to answer a question to point to another without an accepted answer.

Comment: I am not answering your question (though the one i pointed you to does answer the question, its the author who posted the answer), I am pointing to materials that are the same as your question, as you have said nothing that sets it apart from the others. Updating to android 0.8.14. Using Supress warnings. Updating sdk21. Clearning and rebuilding the lint cache

Comment: I appreciate it but none of these solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Android Studio keeps saying that it is not a valid constant.

It isn't a publicly available constant because `USAGE_STAT_SERVICE` is hidden using the `@hide` annotation in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java). This is supported by the lack of `USAGE_STAT_SERVICE` in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

> `getSystemService` has a constraint to only accept `@ServiceName`
>   constants.

This is due to "attribute inspection" and should not affect compilation. It can be [turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26443439/1815485).

I've also successfully gotten an instance of `UsageManagerService` using a direct string.

```
UsageStatsManager manager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
```

Additionally, it is worth noting that the [permission required](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html),

```
android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

is simply flagged by Studio as a permission that can't be granted (technically true based on the documentation) so Studio at this time, does not know about "special" permissions such as these.

Usage Access can be granted in

```
Settings > Security > Apps with usage access
```

Comment: I solved it yesterday using the direct string but had to remove the attribute inspection for the constant. I thought this @hide in the comments had nothing to do with compilation just the documentation.